# How to perform multiple workers to do HTTP request tasks in node js

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, pm2

```js
while (true) {
    const requestIdArray = await db.find()

    # I want to perform the following functions (inside for loop) parallell to increase the efficiency
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        const workingIds = requestIdArray.slice(i*10, i*10+10)
        const apiRes = await thirdPartyAPIRequest(workingIds)
        await work(apiRes) // (20% CPU intense, 40% DB CRUD, 40% HTTP request)
    }
}
```

I want to spread the workload instead of using for loop to perform almost same tasks `work()` every time, what's difference is `requestIdArray` can be different depends on what I get from the database.

I don't know whether I should use [native cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html), or [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to achieve it, and how, since most of the tutorial I can find online is about the backend server load balancing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (true) {
    const requestIdArray = await db.find()

    # I want to perform the following functions (inside for loop) parallell to increase the efficiency
    const workLoad = Array.from({length: 10}, (x, i) => i)
         .map(async i => 
         {
             const workingIds = requestIdArray.slice(i*10, i*10+10)
             const apiRes = await thirdPartyAPIRequest(workingIds)
             await work(apiRes) // (20% CPU intense, 40% DB CRUD, 40% HTTP request)
         });
    await Promise.all(workLoad);
}
```

Comment: So actually no need to use either cluster or pm2 spread the workload in my case? will there be any concurrent issue if I change the same variable inside `work()`?

Comment: Given that your workload, only 20% of the time is in CPU. You can probably run 5 concurrent Tasks with a single node instance/thread.

Comment: If you want more performance, you will need to use multiple thread/cores. But even then, I would probably use `Worker` rather than pm2. Those are process orchestration tools and not task scheduling libraries. They are mostly for keeping a process running. AND THEN EVEN THEN I would not use pm2, because I use systemd like a sane person.

Comment: Thank you, the `Worker` you mentioned is `'node:worker_threads'`?